# Tabernacle construction tools

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle

Where did the Israelites get the necessary tools to construct the tabernacle like: overlay furniture with bronze, to cut stones, to carve wood furniture, to weave fabric and fine linens, to cast gold and silver instruments and utensils?

Comment: First it ought be noted that the Israelites left Egypt with tremendous wealth (Ex. 12:35-36). It also ought be noted that they were a population rife with technical acumen (Ex. 36:4). Ex. 25:29 assumes their ability to forge iron when the instruction is given to create forms so that utensils may be fashioned therefrom. Creating a forge with which to create iron forms, iron tools, iron utensils, etc. would not have been beyond their ability. I assume these skills were acquired during their sojourn in Egypt (which notably is called an iron crucible, Deut. 4:20).

Comment: As slaves they would have had to have been able to use all the tools to perform their duties. As such they would have had all the tools they needed and would have taken them out of Egypt with them.